# Secure POST request against manipulation

Tags: php, post, fat-free-framework, websecurity

I'm currently building a little mini game collection web app, with Fat Free Framework in the Backend (which shouldn't matter too much here).

Now in the games, you can also reach highscores - sending the highscores after finish currently looks something like that:

```
      $.ajax({
        "url": "/submitHighscore",
        "type": "post",
        "data": {
            "game": "Tetris",
            "score": player.score
        }
    });
```

Then, at the /submitHighscore route, I'm receiving that request and enter the info to the database. Now right now, somebody could just intercept that request and change the game and score to enter the database with a different score and game, which is not too great.

My idea I already had was just storing those two things in the session variable, so just set a session with a name of gamePlaying to the current game (once they start it) and just set the session var for the points right before sending the highscore.. That way, I don't need to pass any parameters at all and it's all stored in the session.

I'm however not sure, if it's the best solution - would also include quite some code rewriting.

Do you have a better idea to prevent the manipulation of the POST request?

Comment: you can do csrf, oauth or create something crazy like get user device id encrypt it send it to server get unique id from server send it to user device and start the communication so no one can interfare with the requests. without that key.

Comment: CSRF is a good solution to prevent any user to fire requests directly.

Comment: CSRF is useless to prevent users faking their Highscore. Only way is to handle everything server side if that is even possible for your game, which might need a lot of rewriting as you mentioned it.